# vagrant provisionning in packer build

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant, packer

I would like to create a Vagrant box with Packer. For that I use a packer project on github : [Packer ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://github.com/jose-lpa/packer-ubuntu_14.04)

As they are, the 'packer build' command run correctly and I can use my vagrant box normally. But I want to build a Vagrant box with my configuration and tools pre-install.

For that I create a new script sh file which is run in a provisioners scripts packer template.

```
  "provisioners": [
    {
        "execute_command": "echo 'vagrant'|sudo -S sh '{{.Path}}'",
        "override": {
            "virtualbox-iso": {
                "scripts": [
                    "scripts/base.sh",
                    "scripts/system.sh",
                    "scripts/vagrant.sh",
                    "scripts/python.sh",
                    "scripts/virtualbox.sh",
                    "scripts/docker.sh",
                    "scripts/test-perso.sh",
                    "scripts/cleanup.sh"
                ]
            }
        },
        "type": "shell"
    }
]
```

and the contain of this file :

```
#!/bin/bash -x

apt-get -y install aptitude
apt-get -y install nano
apt-get -y install apache2
apt-get -y install php5
apt-get -y install libapache2-mod-php5
```

All the packer build run correctly without errors. But when a create my Vagrant with this box and launch a cd /etc/apache2 it can't find this. No install of apache2 present.

Because when a run manually this command 'apt-get -y install apache2' on my vagrant, it return me

> Impossible to open the file lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission not allowed)
>   Impossible to lock the directory of administration (/var/lib/dpkg/). Have you the super-user privilege ?

I think have this problem because vagrant user that use for provisionning my vagrant don't have this right privilege. But I can't understand why because I have already this :

base.sh script :

```
# Set up sudo
echo 'vagrant ALL=NOPASSWD:ALL' > /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant
```

vagrant.sh script :

```
# Create the user vagrant with password vagrant
useradd -G sudo -p $(perl -e'print crypt("vagrant", "vagrant")') -m -s /bin/bash -N vagrant

# Install vagrant keys
mkdir -pm 700 /home/vagrant/.ssh
curl -Lo /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys \
  'https://raw.github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant.pub'
chmod 0600 /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown -R vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.ssh
```

builder in template.json packer :

```
  "builders": [
    {
      "boot_command": [
        "<esc><wait>",
        "<esc><wait>",
        "<enter><wait>",
        "/install/vmlinuz<wait>",
        " auto<wait>",
        " console-setup/ask_detect=false<wait>",
        " console-setup/layoutcode=fr<wait>",
        " console-setup/modelcode=pc105<wait>",
        " debconf/frontend=noninteractive<wait>",
        " debian-installer=fr_FR<wait>",
        " fb=false<wait>",
        " initrd=/install/initrd.gz<wait>",
        " kbd-chooser/method=fr<wait>",
        " keyboard-configuration/layout=fr<wait>",
        " keyboard-configuration/variant=fr<wait>",
        " locale=fr_FR<wait>",
        " netcfg/get_domain=vm<wait>",
        " netcfg/get_hostname=vagrant<wait>",
        " noapic<wait>",
        " preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed.cfg<wait>",
        " -- <wait>",
        "<enter><wait>"
      ],
      "boot_wait": "10s",
      "disk_size": 20480,
      "guest_additions_path": "VBoxGuestAdditions_{{.Version}}.iso",
      "guest_os_type": "Ubuntu_64",
      "http_directory": "http",
      "headless": true,
      "iso_checksum": "0501c446929f713eb162ae2088d8dc8b6426224a",
      "iso_checksum_type": "sha1",
      "iso_url": "http://mirrors.mit.edu/ubuntu-releases/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.3-server-amd64.iso",
      "output_directory": "packer-ubuntu-14.04-amd64-virtualbox",
      "shutdown_command": "echo 'vagrant'|sudo -S shutdown -P now",
      "ssh_username": "vagrant",
      "ssh_password": "vagrant",
      "ssh_port": 22,
      "ssh_wait_timeout": "10000s",
      "type": "virtualbox-iso",
      "vboxmanage": [
        [
          "modifyvm",
          "{{.Name}}",
          "--memory",
          "1024"
        ],
        [
          "modifyvm",
          "{{.Name}}",
          "--cpus",
          "1"
        ]
      ],
      "virtualbox_version_file": ".vbox_version",
      "vm_name": "packer-ubuntu-14.04-amd64"
    }
  ]
```

and my preseed.cfg ubuntu :

```
choose-mirror-bin mirror/http/proxy string
d-i base-installer/kernel/override-image string linux-server
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i clock-setup/utc-auto boolean true
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i passwd/user-fullname string vagrant
d-i passwd/user-uid string 900
d-i passwd/user-password password vagrant
d-i passwd/user-password-again password vagrant
d-i passwd/username string vagrant
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server cryptsetup build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev linux-source dkms nfs-common
d-i pkgsel/install-language-support boolean false
d-i pkgsel/update-policy select unattended-upgrades
d-i pkgsel/upgrade select full-upgrade
d-i time/zone string UTC
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard, ubuntu-server
```

Can you tell me how can use a user with sudo access or root user in my provisionning vagrant in packer build ? I would like administrate my vagrant box before launch it all-out.

OS Host : windows 7 pro
OS Guest : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
VM technology : VirtualBox 5.0.10 + Vagrant 1.7.4
VM tools builder : Packer 0.8.6

**edit :**

My debugging log tell me that apache correctly installed and also restarted...

But when a `vagrant up` I think that parameter

> config.vm.box_url

not run correctly because when a locate a non-exist file, it up correctly a virtualbox.

in this case I think that vagrant up don't up the good box and I don't have my apache installation in my vagrant

Comment: whats your output ? specially that you set your script in debug mode. only thing I can think of is to add `apt-get update` at the beginning of the script which is usually best practice before running install

Comment: can you also make `apt-get install -y` instead of `apt-get -y install`

Comment: I tried change `apt-get -y install` to `apt-get install -y` but this is the same result. Tomorrow I will try to output verbose building packer...

Comment: In output debugging, all seems to be good. it install apache, config this and also restarting this. But When a connect into vagrant a never find files for installation apache...very very strange

Answer (score 1):

do the following:

```
#vagrant box list
```

remove all or uneeded boxes:

```
#vagrant box remove <box>
```

run vagrant with the new box:

```
#vagrant up --provision
```

or just start the box without provisioning:

```
#vagrant up --no-provision
```

and finally:

```
#vagrant ssh
```